# Show specific tooltip onClick on child component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have a Parent component rendering some radio buttons as a child component. I want to show a tooltip when the user click in one of the radio button. And i have different tooltip messages for each radio button. I am using the index to show this tooltip. But how can i tell the child component to show this clicked tooltip based on the `activeIndex`?

Parent

```
const [showPopup, setShowPopup] = useState(false);
const [activeIndex, setActiveIndex] = useState(-1);

 return (
    <div>
      {options?.map((option,index) => (
        <RadioBtn
          key={index}
          label={option.label}
          value={option.value}
          showTooltip={showTooltip}
           activeIndex={activeIndex}
          onClick={() => {
            setShowTooltip(curr => !curr);
            setActiveIndex(index);
          }}
        />
      ))}
    </div>
  );
```

**Child**

```
const popupMessage = (<div>{infoContent}</div>);
 
return (
    <div>
      <Popup open={showPopup}>
        <PopupPositionReference>
          <div onClick={props.onClick}>
            <input
              ref={iRef => {
                ref(iRef);
                inputRef.current = iRef;
              }}
              type="radio"
              checked={isChecked}
              {...props}
              {...rest}
            />
            <label htmlFor={id}>
              {label}
            </label>
          </div>
        </PopupPositionReference>
        {popupMessage && <PopupContent>{popupMessage}</PopupContent>}
      </Popup>
    </div>
  );
```

Answer (score 0):

**Method 1:**

If you have permission to mutate your **options** object, you can modify it to something like this.

```
const options = [
{ label: 'option1', value: 'option1 value', tooltip: 'you have selected option1'},
{ label: 'option2', value: 'option2 value', tooltip: 'you have selected option2'}
];
```

And on your onClick handler you can set the the tooltip message just by using `setTooltipTitle(option.tooltip)`

**Method 2:**

you can have a array of tooltip messages and then access them using the index;

```
const tooltips = ['tooltip 1', 'tooltip 2', 'tooltip 3']
```

Later you can access tooltips using the `activeIndex` what you are setting on **onClick** event